# G/ in front of a QSL calls sign: SV1ABA

Tags: qsl-card

I am indexing my father's QSL call sign cards.

I came across a QSL card sign `SV1ABA`. It starts with a `G/`.

What does the `G/` represent? I know `SV1ABA` is Greece, but this card is Northwest England Liverpool.

Comment: Hi Anastasia! It seems you've gotten two high-quality answers; would you be as kind as marking one of them as "accepted", if it *did* answer your question? That way, your question gets marked as resolved, and future readers will know that yes, that answer seemed correct to the person asking. After all, the collective goal of this site's user community is to build a searchable library of questions & answers that is somewhat trustworthy (which sets this site apart from a lot of scattered statements on the internet, especially in times of automatic text generation overwhelming search engines).

Answer (score 6):

There is an agreement between a group of countries (the CEPT T/R 61-01 agreement - described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_international_operation#CEPT_License)) that allows radio amateurs from any of the countries in the agreement to operate in any of the other countries - but they have to use their own callsign with the prefix of the country they are visiting as a prefix.

So the QSL you have there is from G/SV1ABA - which is one SV1ABA when they were operating in England (G). If they were in Scotland, it would have been GM/SV1ABA. If from France, it would have been F/SV1ABA. Et cetera.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone will correct me on this, but the G/ probably means that SV1ABA was visiting England when he made this contact.

The [G prefix](https://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/international-prefixes/) is assigned to hams in Great Britain, e.g. G3TXQ.